# (AJAX Control Toolkit) DropShadow Opacity property doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, opacity, dropshadow

I'm working on ASP.NET project. When I put DropShadow extender inside a panel there is a new shadow effect but it doesn't change after i set different opacity value. Shadow looks the same with values 0, 0.1 , 0.5 and 1. I also tried values bigger then one. Anyone knows why is it so?

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            hrthartartart6</asp:Panel>
        <asp:DropShadowExtender ID="Panel1_DropShadowExtender" runat="server" 
            Enabled="True" Opacity="0.1" TargetControlID="Panel1">
        </asp:DropShadowExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must not be changing the correct CSS, can you post some code?

Comment: I added the code. It is a simple sample asp.net website with a single panel with dropshadow added. Shadow is visible but i can't change it with "opacity" parameter.

Comment: @rick he's actually referring to the Opacity property of the DropShadowExtender control (which *is* kind of confusing, considering Opacity is also a CSS property).

Comment: I experienced the same issue. Apparently work only Opacity=".25", Opacity=".5", Opacity=".75", Opacity="1"